# Office Web add-in using Svelte

Tags: excel, svelte, office-addins, rollup

I have started developing my first [Excel web add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/develop-overview) and would like to use Svelte with rollup as the UI framework.

I used `yo office` to generate a starter template, not using a framework, but with Typescript for coding.

If I look at the generated project it consists of 3 parts

1. The manifest, used to register the add-in in office365.
2. Lots of specifik npm packages specific for office-add-in debugging
3. The site that should be loaded into the webview used by Excel

So I am looking for help with setting up svelte for office web add-in development and also some ideas for running only the svelte app without Excel for faster development of new features.
No reason to load Excel for styling or creating forms and rest services.

If this is the wrong forum for such a question then please point me in the right direction.

Comment: StackOverflow is *not* a forum at all, so yes, this might be the wrong place. Try the [official Discord](https://discord.com/invite/yy75DKs).

Comment: View answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/75716025/12526328