# Can you build an Excel task pane add-in with Svelte?

Tags: excel-addins

I'm thinking about developing an Excel add-in as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator).

Would that be possible with Svelte - and do you know of any guides/help if yes?

I have looked through the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aszwh_h5MtM), and I'm about worried about the usage of webpack.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible to create office addin using Svelte.

1. Create svelte app using

```
npm init vite
```

2. Enter project name, framework (select `Svelte`) and variant (`JavaScript`, `TypeScript`)
3. Now create two files
   The content can be taken from following project or [generator-office](https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office)

   (1) [taskpane.html](https://github.com/krmanik/Office-Addin-TaskPane-Svelte/blob/main/taskpane.html) (2) [commands.html](https://github.com/krmanik/Office-Addin-TaskPane-Svelte/blob/main/commands.html)
4. Install these dependencies

```
npm install @microsoft/office-js @types/office-js office-addin-debugging vite-plugin-html --dev
```

5. Note: It needs to include following in the two html pages.

```html
  <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"> 
  </script>

  <!-- For more information on Fluent UI, visit https://developer.microsoft.com/fluentui#/. -->
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-core/11.0.0/css/fabric.min.css"
  />
```

6. Add this to App.svelte, so that the page will load after office is ready.

```html
<script>
  let isOfficeInitialized = false;
  window.onload = function () {
    const Office = window.Office;
    Office.onReady(() => {
      console.log("Office Ready");
      isOfficeInitialized = true;
    });
  };

  const click = async () => {
    return Word.run(async (context) => {
      /**
       * Insert your Word code here
       */

      // insert a paragraph at the end of the document.
      const paragraph = context.document.body.insertParagraph(
        "Hello World",
        Word.InsertLocation.end
      );

      // change the paragraph color to blue.
      paragraph.font.color = "blue";

      await context.sync();
    });
  };
</script>

{#if isOfficeInitialized}
  <main>
    <div style="margin-top: 20px; font-size: 18px;">
      <div>
        Modify the source files, then click <b>Run</b>.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="run-button">
      <button onclick={click}>Run</button>
    </div>
  </main>
{/if}
```

7. Create [commands.ts](https://github.com/krmanik/Office-Addin-TaskPane-Svelte/blob/main/src/commands.ts) to `src/` for `commands.html`
8. Edit [vite.config.ts](https://github.com/krmanik/Office-Addin-TaskPane-Svelte/blob/main/vite.config.ts) to build the two pages for Office Addin

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { createHtmlPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-html'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    svelte(),
    createHtmlPlugin({
      minify: true,
      pages: [
        {
          entry: 'src/main.ts',
          filename: 'taskpane.html',
          template: 'taskpane.html',
          injectOptions: {
            data: {
              injectScript: `<script src="./main.js"></script>`,
            },
          },
        },
        {
          entry: 'src/commands.ts',
          filename: 'commands.html',
          template: 'commands.html',
          injectOptions: {
            data: {
              injectScript: `<script src="./commands.js"></script>`,
            },
          },
        }
      ]
    })
  ],
})
```

9. Add [manifest.xml](https://github.com/krmanik/Office-Addin-TaskPane-Svelte/tree/main/manifests) file to project
10. Now add run script to package.json

```json
scripts: {
    "start": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml",
    "start:desktop": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml desktop",
    "start:web": "office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml web",
    "stop": "office-addin-debugging stop manifest.xml",
    "validate": "office-addin-manifest validate manifest.xml"
}
```

I have also created a project for creating office addin. It can also be used. https://github.com/krmanik/Office-Addin-TaskPane-Svelte

Answer (score 1):

Well... let's break it down

### Is it possible?

**Short answer:** yes

**Long answer:** the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator) clearly states that `Excel add-in` still uses `jQuery` for logic manipulations. If your question was about `Angular` or `react` it would probably be a hard NO since those frameworks use an engine that should be included as part of solution. This kind of dependencies when dealing with plugins development are pretty hard to implement and maintain as a function of time so it's better to use very lightweight, non-core dependencies instead. Since you are asking about `svelte` - it is "compiled" into a `bundle` that contains pure code (based on your app logic). So - as long as your app rely on the load event sequence described in the docs - you are good to go.

### Do you really need Webpack?

**Short answer:** no

**Long answer:** svelte can be deployed using `rollup` instead - which is more suitable for micro-applications (such as yours). So, if you feel that webpack (somehow) is blocking your work pipeline - just use `svelete` default configuration with `rollup` and you are ready to go

### Your workflow

1. Create a very simple `svelte` app (my suggestion - try to take the example in the docs and implement it using `svelte`)
2. Test it locally (just verify it works)
3. Build it (you should ended up with 3 files - 1 `html` file in `public` directory and 2 other files in `public/build` directory - 1 `js` file and 1 `css file` (both called `bundle`)
4. Here's the tricky part - the `html` file does nothing - just loading the `css` and `js` files. In your case - you don't really need it
5. Change the `bundle.css` file to `Home.css` file
6. Change the `bundle.js` file to `Home.js` file and put your app inside the add-in main function

   ```
    'use strict';

    (function () {

      Office.onReady(function() {
        // Office is ready
        YOUR SVELTE APP CODE SHOULD BE PLACED HERE
      });

    })();
   ```
7. Pack your add-in and test it

### Technical notes

- If Excel blocks the creation of new elements (using dynamic injection) - this approach will NOT work (since your entire app is generated by your `js` file)
- Please refer to this [article](https://medium.com/@PepsRyuu/why-i-use-rollup-and-not-webpack-e3ab163f4fd3) for more information about packing your app
- Try to make your app as lightweight and small-size as possible just to avoid the risk of exceeding the [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/resource-limits-and-performance-optimization#excel-add-ins) allowed for add-ins

Comment: @DauleDK - please share your experience so future developers will have more references and better resolution about this answer. thanks!