# How to load and use office.js in Sveltekit

Tags: office-js, sveltekit

Here are the ways I have tried in a +page.svelte

```js
  onMount(async () => {
    const module = await import('https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js');
    });
```

This seems to try to load but has the following error - "Uncaught (in promise) Office Web Extension script library file name should be office.js or office.debug.js."

Also tried

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"> 
    import { browser } from '$app/environment';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';


    let isOfficeInitialized = false;
    if (browser) {
            console.log("browser load");
        window.onload = function () {
        console.log("window onload");
        const Office = window.Office;
        Office.onReady(() => {
                console.log("Office Ready");
            isOfficeInitialized = true;
        });
        }
    }
```

console log shows "browser load" but not "window onload"

and

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js">
    import { browser } from '$app/environment';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let isOfficeInitialized = false;
    if (browser) {
        console.log('load in browser');
        const Office = window.Office;
        if (Office) {
            console.log('Office assigned');
            Office.onReady(() => {
                console.log('Office Ready');
                isOfficeInitialized = true;
            });
        }
    }
```

console log shows "load in browser" but not "Office assigned"

Has anyone been able to use office.js in SvelteKit? There is a post, [Can you build an Excel task pane add-in with Svelte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72044122/can-you-build-an-excel-task-pane-add-in-with-svelte), about using Svelte for a web add-in but I could not find if it has been done using SvelteKit. I might be going about it wrong so any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use three backquotes around your code. (I edited the question).

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that also and edited. Duplicate edits must work!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I currently have and it seems to be loading and working

app.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%sveltekit.assets%/favicon.png" />

        <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642863/office-js-nullifies-browser-history-functions-breaking-history-usage -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Office js deletes window.history.pushState and window.history.replaceState. Cache them and restore them
            window._historyCache = {
                replaceState: window.history.replaceState,
                pushState: window.history.pushState
            };
        </script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Office js deletes window.history.pushState and window.history.replaceState. Restore them
            window.history.replaceState = window._historyCache.replaceState;
            window.history.pushState = window._historyCache.pushState;
        </script>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        %sveltekit.head%
    </head>
    <body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover">
        <div style="display: contents">%sveltekit.body%</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

+page.svelte

```
<script>
    import { browser } from '$app/environment';

    let isOfficeInitialized = false;
    if (browser) {
        console.log('load in browser');
        const Office = window.Office;
        if (Office) {
            console.log('Office assigned');
            Office.onReady(() => {
                console.log('Office Ready');
                isOfficeInitialized = true;
            });
        }
    }

    let itemSubject = "";

    function setSubject() {
        const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
        if (item)
        {
            itemSubject = item.subject;
        }
        else
        {
            itemSubject = "N/A";
        }
    }

</script>


<h1>Welcome to the Add-in TaskPane</h1>

<div>
    <button on:click={setSubject}>
        Current Item Subject {itemSubject}
    </button>
</div>
```

I am not sure this is the best way so am open to other answers.

Comment: What is the path that you are using in the manifest file for taskpane resource?  Im having issues with my add-in loading in the taskpane, and struggling to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `svelte:head`

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from "svelte";

  onMount(() => {
    const Office = window.Office;
    Office.onReady(() => {
      console.log("Office Ready!");
    });
  });
</script>

<svelte:head>
  <script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"
  ></script>
</svelte:head>
```

Edit: This will display an error in your IDE (`Office` is not property of `window`). To fix that (and add types!) install `@types/office-js`.

Comment: I tried this solution and Office seems to load fine. But when I add some svelte logic, everything seems to break. reloading the page/add-in doesn't load office anymore and sveltekit won't run on:click events anymore. Maybe the later Sveltekit versions broke this method of loading Office.js. Has anybody tried this lately and got it to work correctly?

Comment: ok, seems that @dkoeder is right to restore the window.history. if you dont then sveltekit breaks. you could probably use plain svelte by loading office in svelte:head but kit really needs the history to route properly.